# How can I store a very little value (approximately 10^(-32)) in numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have to store little numbers in a numpy array. At the and, min should be around 10^(-32).  It returns with the proper value if it is up to 10^(-14).  Is there any way to fix this problem? Thanks for the answers!

```
import numpy as np
import math
def Modify(array):
    maxIndex = np.argmax(array)
    for j in range(array.shape[0]):
        if (j == maxIndex):
            if (j == (len(array)-1)):
                nextIndex = (j + 1) % array.shape[0]
                prevIndex = (j - 1) % array.shape[0]
                array[nextIndex] = (array[prevIndex]) + (array[nextIndex]) - (array[j])
                new_array = np.delete(array, [prevIndex, (j % array.shape[0])])

            elif (j == 0):

                 nextIndex = (j + 1) % array.shape[0]
                 prevIndex = (j - 1) % array.shape[0]
                 array[prevIndex] = (array[prevIndex]) + (array[nextIndex]) - (array[j])
                 new_array = np.delete(array, [(j % array.shape[0]), nextIndex])

            elif (j != 0 and j % 2 == 0):
                   nextIndex = (j + 1) % array.shape[0]
                   prevIndex = (j - 1) % array.shape[0]
                   array[j] = (array[prevIndex]) + (array[nextIndex]) - (array[j])
                   new_array = np.delete(array, [prevIndex, nextIndex])

            elif(j != (len(array)-1) and j % 2 !=0 ):
                     nextIndex = (j + 1) % array.shape[0]
                     prevIndex = (j - 1) % array.shape[0]
                     array[j] = (array[prevIndex]) + (array[nextIndex]) - (array[j])
                     new_array = np.delete(array, [prevIndex, nextIndex])

    return new_array
```

if **name** == "**main**":

```
a=10000
i=0
m=0
e = 0
E = 0
k=0
min=1
for i in range(a):
  chain = np.random.uniform(0, 1, 256)
  chain = chain.astype('float64')
  for k in range(len(chain)):
      chain[k] = math.log(chain[k])
  while (chain.shape[0] > 4):
      chain = Modify(chain)
  chain[0] = math.exp(chain[0])
  chain[1] = math.exp(chain[1])
  chain[2] = math.exp(chain[2])
  chain[3] = math.exp(chain[3])
  chain[2] = chain[0] + chain[2]
  E=-math.sqrt((chain[1]**2)+(chain[3]**2)+(chain[2]**2)+2*chain[1]*chain[3])
  e=-math.sqrt((chain[1]**2)+(chain[3]**2)+(chain[2]**2)-2*chain[1]*chain[3])
  m = abs(e-E)
  if m < min:
      min=m
print(min)
```

Comment: Dont forget to mark the answer as accepted if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

The underlying problem here is not about storing numbers that small, but rather about the finite precision of floating-point numbers (which is a bit less than 16 decimal digits for 64-bit floats). If the (true) relative difference between `e` and `E` is smaller than this precision, `e - E` will evaluate to zero. This is called "catastrophic cancellation."

A simple and effective way to get around this is to expand `e - E` in a power series about `2*chain[1]*chain[3]` = 0 and take the first non-zero term. If we pull out the common terms between `e` and `E` into separate variables, we have

```
term_1 = chain[1]**2 + chain[3]**2 + chain[2]**2
term_2 = 2*chain[1]*chain[3]
E = -math.sqrt(term_1 + term_2)
e = -math.sqrt(term_1 - term_2)
m = abs(e - E)
```

The first non-zero term in the series works out to `term_2 / sqrt(term_1)`. The next term is of order `(term_2/term_1)^3`, so we can safely truncate the series before that if `(term_2/term_1)^2 < 1e-16` (16 decimal digits), or `term_2 / term_1 < 1e-8`. If the ratio is larger than that, our approximation might be slightly off, but at that point the normal `e - E` works just fine.

The final code (with some extra numpy simplifications):

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = 10000
    min = 1
    for i in range(a):
        chain = np.log(np.random.uniform(0, 1, 256))
        while chain.shape[0] > 4:
            chain = Modify(chain)
        chain = np.exp(chain)
        chain[2] = chain[2] + chain[0]
        term_1 = chain[1]**2 + chain[3]**2 + chain[2]**2
        term_2 = 2 * chain[1] * chain[3]
        e = -math.sqrt(term_1 - term_2)
        E = -math.sqrt(term_1 + term_2)
        m = abs(e - E)
        if abs(term_2 / term_1) < 1e-8:
            # use power series approximation for e - E instead
            # we only need the first term: the next term is O(term_2/term_1)^2
            # smaller, which is less than machine epsilon
            m = term_2 / math.sqrt(term_1)
        if m < min:
            min = m
    print(min)
```